# How can I construct an elapsed time column from a column of pandas.datetime64?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, timedelta, datetime64

I have a dataframe containing a column with:

```
3    3/20/2017 8:00:36 PM
4    3/20/2017 8:01:09 PM
5    3/20/2017 8:01:43 PM
Name: ActualTime, dtype: object
```

I want to create a column with the elapsed time in seconds.

```
0
33
67
```

Tried things like:

```
t0 = pd.to_datetime(x,unit='s')
t1 = pd.to_datetime(y,unit='s')
t0-t1

3   NaT
4   NaT
Name: ActualTime, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using:

```
df['ElapsedTime'] = (df['ActualTime'] - df['ActualTime'].iloc[0]).astype("timedelta64[m]")
```

I ended up using minutes instead for convenience. For seconds:

```
df['ElapsedTime'] = (df['ActualTime'] - df['ActualTime'].iloc[0]).astype("timedelta64[s]")
```